# LargeImageDownSize iOS sample code, restrict zoom in level

Tags: ios, ios4

My current requirement is to display large(3000 * 3000) image on `UIImageView` with zoom in functionality. I came across few posts saying `CATiledLayer` is the way to go.

I have downloaded Apple sample code ["LargeImageDownSizing"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011173-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) in which using `CATiledLayer` large image can be displayed with zoom in zoom out functionality. My problem is, in this sample code I have to restrict zoom in to certain level, currently it is infinite.

Any help on this would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't thouroughly looked at the sample code from Apple, but I guess that simply setting the `maximumZoomScale` property on the UIScrollView should do the trick

Comment: I did try that, it's currently set to 5.0f, i set it to 2.0f but still the result is same, i am able to zoom in infinite.

Answer (score 0):

// try this.. Best option for Zooming Image with UIScrollview

```
imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height)];
        imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.50;
        imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.00;
        imageScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        imageScrollView.delegate = self;
        [self addSubview:imageScrollView];

imageView_temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height)];
        imageView_temp.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        imageView_temp.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [imageView_temp setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        originalImagePos = imageView_temp.center;
        [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView_temp];
        imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView_temp.frame.size.width, imageView_temp.frame.size.height);


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    return imageView_temp;
}

-(void)resetImageZoom {

    NSLog(@"Resetting any image zoom");

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);

    imageView_temp.transform = transform;

    [imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeZero];

    imageView_temp.center = originalImagePos;
}
```